# JavaScript: возможно ли избежать конфликта с сочетаниями клавиш браузера?

Tags: javascript

При решении задачи добавления управления сочетаниями клавиш в своё веб-приложение столкнулся с тем, что многие "хорошие" сочетания клавиш уже заняты браузером. Но хуже всего то, то все у каждого браузера свои сочетания клавиш.

В принципе, ответ "С этим ничего нельзя сделать. JavaScript не может вмешиваться в настройки браузера" вполне предсказуем. Но как с этой проблемой борятся в других приложениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто:
Назначайте и отлавливайте что Вам нужно, а браузеру можно сказать чтобы не делал своё действие (установите фокус на страницу сниппета, чтобы вводить там клавиши):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 83){ // Ctrl + s, браузерное сочетание
    e.preventDefault(); // Отменяем действие браузера
    console.info("Сохранить страницу, юнец, не позволю тебе я!");
  }
});
```

Мана по [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Отмечу также что некоторые действия отменить нельзя, т. к. их "владелец" - OS, а не браузер:
`Alt + F4`, `Ctrl + Shift + Esc` и т. д.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+S` не получилось отменить для Chrome

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, так в хроме "Сохранить как" это `Ctrl + S`. А `Ctrl + Shift + S` вообще ничего не делает.

Comment: Опечатался:) `Crtl+Shift+T` не получилось. Я и на `Ctrl+T` и на `Ctrl+Shift+T` поставил `e.preventDefault();`, но всё равно оба действия срабатывают...

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, это сочетание относится к браузеру, а не к странице, поэтому не работает отмена. Однако, расширения хрома могут переопределить даже такие сочетания.

Comment: Понятно, вообщем предел возможностей здесь:) Даже если мы можем обращаться к расширению из кода, надо заставить пользователя установить это расширение, да и будет работать оно только в Chrome. Я всё правильно сказал?

Comment: Хром правильно делает - код вкладки должен только собой управлять и никак не влиять на остальные вкладки и браузер. Представьте что было бы: одна злая страница блокирует клавиши/ввод всего браузера и можно только убить весь браузер. Да, расширение делается под браузер, но, вероятно, есть похожие возможности под другие браузеры. Хотя заставлять юзера ставить расширения для просмотра своего сайта - это сильно :)